# how to identify which dashboard is using a particular report

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have a few reports i want to delete, but some of these reports are been used in dashboards because of which we are not able to delete them.

Is there a way to identify which dashboard is using a particular report?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a custom Report type to do this.

Click on Setup...

App Setup...

Create...

Report Types...

New Custom Report Types...

Wizard Step 1... Primary Object = Reports, Name it, Store it. Deploy it.

Step 2...Click on little grey box below Reports Primary Object box. Select "Dashboard Component". Save.

After you save, you can Edit Layout to add or remove fields. But this should be enough to do what you want.

After you've created your custom report, go to the Report page, and click the Create New Custom Report button. (option may be different if you are using new Report Builder).  Find your new custom report in the Category that you saved it.
Set filters as necessary and run report.